# How to attach data to temporize event?

Tags: heroku

I use the Heroku Temporize add-on to schedule tasks.
The [temporize documentation](http://docs.temporize.apiary.io/#post-%2Fv1%2Fevents%2F%7Bdate%7D%2F%7Burl%7D) says:

> Any post data provided with the request carries state data your
>   application uses to decide how to process the event. For instance, the
>   'data' field could contain an account number for a user in your system
>   or a chunk of data to be processed.

I tried to post text/plain, url-encoded and JSON data but I never receive any data on my endpoint.